# Cannot find project's current branch in the bottom-right corner of Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

I am using Android Studio version 3.1.2.
Something has changed after studio update. And now I am not able to find project's current branch in the bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Accidentally I have unchecked Status bar option present under View section under main menu.

Answer (score 22):

Had same issue in Studio Arctic Fox.
And in Menus Option >> View >> Appearance >> Status Bar Widgets >> Git Branch(not present)

So, doing invalidate Caches/Restart fixed my issue.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue in Android Studio Chipmunk (The Arctic Fox).

Steps to Resolve the Issue.
From Menu option go to View -> Appearance -> Status Bar Widgets -> Git Branch (Check it).

Will work.

Answer (score 7):

With the new UI in Android Studio Giraffe it is now on the window top just after the project name.

Comment: I feel so much boomer xd

Answer (score 3):

In android studio hedgedog with new android studio UI enabled, I had to search(Ctrl+N) "Show Git Branch" action and enable it.

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio Hedgehog
Top menu bar > View > Appearance > Status Bar Widgets > Git Branch

Answer (score 0):

Try this
click on vcs -> enable version control integration.